# sec_to_time() function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.0

MySQL has a cool function [`sec_to_time()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) which converts your number of seconds to hh:mm:ss

I've read through the mailing lists and am basically trying to implement the following:

```
MySQL:
select sec_to_time(sum(unix_timestamp(enddate) - unix_timestamp(startdate))) from foo;

PostgreSQL:
select XXX(sum(date_part('epoch',enddate) - date_part('epoch',startdate))) from foo;
```

I just need to know what XXX is/can be.  I've tried a lot of combinations of the documented functions .

Please let how to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: [justify_interval()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.htm), perhaps?

Comment: it throws ERROR:  function justify_interval(double precision) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT justify_interval(sum(date_part('epoch',log_reports.lo...

Comment: [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html) maybe? Pass your timestamp and specify the format you want to output to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
regress=# SELECT to_char( (9999999 ||' seconds')::interval, 'HH24:MM:SS' );
  to_char   
------------
 2777:00:39
(1 row)
```

Here's a function that produces a `text` formatted value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sec_to_time(bigint) RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT to_char( ($1|| ' seconds')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS');
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL' IMMUTABLE;
```

eg:

```
regress=# SELECT sec_to_time(9999999);
 sec_to_time 
-------------
 2777:00:39
(1 row)
```

If you'd prefer an `INTERVAL` result, use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sec_to_time(bigint) RETURNS interval AS $$
SELECT justify_interval( ($1|| ' seconds')::interval);
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL' IMMUTABLE;
```

... which will produce results like:

```
SELECT sec_to_time(9999999);
       sec_to_time       
-------------------------
 3 mons 25 days 17:46:39
(1 row)
```

Don't cast an `INTERVAL` to `TIME` though; it'll discard the days part. Use `to_char(theinterval, 'HH24:MI:SS)` to convert it to `text` without truncation instead.

Comment: @Sathish No worries. You can format `INTERVAL`s with [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html) by the way.

Comment: @Sathish Actually, the whole thing is better done with `to_char`. See updated answer.

Comment: The first statement is using the wrong format. The format should be 'HH24:MI:SS' and not 'HH24:MM:SS' because the minutes are not being calculated correctly.